# Kaniko: Build more than one dockerfile in pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, kaniko

I have a gitlab repository that contains multiple dockerfiles. I know that this is not ideal.
I now want to use my gitlab pipeline to create one image per dockerfile using kaniko and pushing it to its corresponding AWS ECR. Of course I can define a job for each dockerfile but this results in duplication of code and overhead in runtime. Is it possible to build multiple dockerfiles at the same time in one job? A possible approach would be to pass a string array with the dockerfiles, and then iterate over the corresponding kaniko command. However, since kaniko only provides a busybox shell, all this is not really nice and easy. Ideas?

Comment: Is the number of dockerfiles constant?

Comment: I would like to create a template that I can reuse for different repositories. Therefore the number of dockerfiles is not constant. But I would appreciate any approach, even if it does not solve the problem completely.

Comment: Why not using in a single job a for loop with the list of the Dockerfiles and pass each to kaniko using the switch `--dockerfile`?

Comment: @DavideMadrisan Yep, thats what I did (and mean by "iterate over a string array with the dockerfiles"), but loops in busybox are not that intuitive or nice. Therefore I dont like that approach. But it seems to be the best way to go for now.

Comment: Looping is the way to go, but make sure you use the flag "--cleanup" to get rid of the last build in the container.